# Retransmit a feed to multiple users

Tags: api, architecture, stream, message-queue

I have the following problem to solve and I wanted to know what options I have to do it. Basically I have a feed that comes to me via a socket and I need to retransmit it to multiple computers.
First of all I want to make a beta version as fast and simple as possible, for a maximum of 250 connections. Then in the future I will build a full version with an architecture that supports scaling in number of connections and perhaps a little more in the size of packages.

Some more detailed data:

- The packages have a weight of 2KB approximately.
- At peak moments we will send about 50 packets per second. (1 pack every 20 ms)
- In the beta version if a package does not reach one of the consumers its not a problem but in the full version it is.
- I would like to push the messages and not have the consumers pull them, but for the beta version its not mandatory.
- In the beta version I do not need authentication but in the full version I do.

I was researching and I found that I could use:

- Message Queue, ie RabbitMQ
- An Api Stream like Twitter

Are there other alternatives? What technology and tools do you recommend me to use for beta version and full version?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

AMQP is a good choice, as you've mentioned.

You also can check out DDS: http://opendds.org/about/dds_overview.html